# Facebook Profile Picture Large

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, image

I am having trouble trying to request the large version of the users profile picture on Facebook.. in my graph path I'm doing:

```
NSString *requestPath = @"me/?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email,birthday,verified,picture";
```

The picture field in there only gives me the small version of the profile picture, but i need the large and the normal version.. i already tried changing picture to picture_large, pic_large, image_large but none of this works..

Please, i already read the documentations, so don't bother answering if you plan on telling me to read it again.. I'm asking this here because i already searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks,
Newton

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER/picture?type=large
```

Where *USER* can be either the user id or the user name.

That returns a redirect to the static image url, as written in the [User object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

> HTTP 302 redirect to URL of the user's profile picture (use
>   ?type=square | small | normal | large to request a different photo).

Comment: I know this works on the web, but I'm not doing an http request, I'm working with iOS, so i need to use the notation that i listed in my question.. thanks for the reply

Comment: I don't see how's that relevant. Instead of asking for the picture from the api, ask for everything else and then just add to the returned data these two url strings: `http://graph.facebook.com/USER/picture?type=normal` and `http://graph.facebook.com/USER/picture?type=large`. You can just use those urls, like any other.

Comment: Mr ApplrBR, may I know how to get image data with out http/https request?

Comment: @Venu I don't know man, thats what I'm asking... AT Nitzan i know what u mean, but i was looking for a way to just use the API, thought it was possible... will try the http

Comment: The api will just bring you back the url, it won't bring you the actual picture. Using my method is better since the resulting response from facebook will be smaller in size which means a (bit) faster response. Why ask facebook for information you already have??

Answer (score 31):

The short answer you are looking for is `picture.type(large)`

I was looking for the same thing and found the answer using Facebook Graph API explorer found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Now if I use the following code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                             parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture.type(large),id,email,name,username"
                                                                    forKey:@"fields"]
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){[self fbRequestCompleted:result];}];
```

the "picture" key in the "result" dictionary has the value of the large picture's URL.

Comment: Hi Murat....picture.type(large) works perfectly but I still couldn't find a way to get the pic like picture?height=320&width=320....it brings me a "null" URL....is there a way to get square pic as I need using NSDictionary as you used for parameters?

Answer (score 6):

Nitzan Tomer's response is still correct for iOS; if you want to get the large version of the user's profile picture using Facebook's iOS API, you can just write:

```
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"large" forKey:@"type"] andDelegate:self];
```

And you will get the image data in the *result* object, in this delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
```